# JQuery slider navigation dots not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm making a custom jquery slider, the slider works perfectly but the navigation dots don't work for some reason, if I click on a navigation dot the corresponding slider should be made visible but it just displays blank instead.

This is the important part of the code, where I append the dots depending of the number of sliders and where I register click events on the dots :

```js
$('.slider').each(function(){
        $('.gran_slider_big_navegation_container').append('<span class="dot"></span>');
    });
 
 
 $('.dot').click(function(){
        index = $(this).eq();
  console.log(index);
        $('.slider').removeClass('active_slider'); 
     $('.slider').eq(index).addClass('active_slider');
  show_index = index;
  
    });
```

Here is the full code of the slider as it is right now:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 
 var interval = 12000;
 var sliders = $('.slider');
 var dots = $('.dot');
 var index = 0;
 var show_index = 0;
 
 
 $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
 $('.dot').eq(show_index).addClass('active_dot');
 console.log(show_index);
 console.log(sliders.length);
 
 
 
 
 setInterval(function() {
        
  if(show_index == (sliders.length- 1)){
   
   
   $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider');
            show_index = 0; // set it here
      $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
            $('.dot').removeClass('active_dot');   
   $('.dot').eq(show_index).addClass('active_dot');   
   console.log(show_index);
  }
  
  else{
   
   
   $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider');
            show_index = show_index + 1; // set it here 
      $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
   $('.dot').removeClass('active_dot');   
   $('.dot').eq(show_index).addClass('active_dot');
            console.log(show_index);   
  }
  
    }, interval);
 
 
 
 
 $('.prev').click(function(){
  
  console.log('clicked prev');
  
  if(show_index == 0){
   
   
   $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider');
            show_index = (sliders.length - 1);// set it here
      $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
            $('.dot').removeClass('active_dot');   
   $('.dot').eq(show_index).addClass('active_dot');   
   console.log(show_index);
  }
  
  else{
   
   $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider');
            show_index = show_index - 1; // set it here 
      $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
   $('.dot').removeClass('active_dot');   
   $('.dot').eq(show_index).addClass('active_dot');
            console.log(show_index);   
  }
    });
 
 
 
 $('.next').click(function(){
  
  console.log('clicked next');
  
  if(show_index == (sliders.length- 1)){
   
   
   $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider');
            show_index = 0; // set it here
      $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
            $('.dot').removeClass('active_dot');   
   $('.dot').eq(show_index).addClass('active_dot');
   console.log(show_index);
  }
  
  else{
   
   
   $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider');
            show_index = show_index + 1; // set it here 
      $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
   $('.dot').removeClass('active_dot');   
   $('.dot').eq(show_index).addClass('active_dot');
            console.log(show_index);   
  }
    });
 
 
 
 
 $('.slider').each(function(){
        $('.gran_slider_big_navegation_container').append('<span class="dot"></span>');
    });
 
 
 $('.dot').click(function(){
        index = $(this).eq();
  console.log(index);
        $('.slider').removeClass('active_slider'); 
     $('.slider').eq(index).addClass('active_slider');
  show_index = index;
  
    });
 
 
});
```

```css
/*GRAN SLIDER START*/
.gran_slider_maincontainer{width:100%; height:100vh; display:flex; flex-direction:column; overflow:hidden;}
.gran_slider_big_container{width:100%; position:relative; height:90vh; overflow:hidden;}
.prev{cursor:pointer; position:absolute; left:20px; transition:all 1000ms ease; opacity:0; z-index:9999999999999999999999999999; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); font-size:20px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);}
.next{cursor:pointer; position:absolute; right:20px; transition:all 1000ms ease; opacity:0; z-index:9999999999999999999999999999;  top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); font-size:20px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);}
.gran_slider_big_navegation_container{width:auto; height:30px; display:flex; align-items:center; position:absolute; bottom:25px; right:50px; z-index:9999999999999999999999999999;}
.dot{width:15px; height:15px;  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); transition: all 2000ms ease; margin:0px 6px; border-radius:50%; cursor:pointer;}
.gran_slider_big_container:hover .prev{opacity:1;}
.gran_slider_big_container:hover .next{opacity:1;}
.gran_slider_big_item_container{display:none; width:100%; height:100%; position:relative; overflow:hidden;}
.gran_slider_big_item_gradient_overlay{width:100%; height:100%; z-index:3; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4); position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;}
.gran_slider_big_item_image{width:100%; height:100%; z-index:2; background-size:cover;}
.gran_slider_big_item_texts_container{width:55%; height:auto; display:flex; flex-direction:column; padding:10px;}
.gran_slider_big_item_texts_title{font-size:45px; color:white; font-weight:600; margin-bottom:30px; text-shadow:5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);}
.gran_slider_big_item_texts_description{font-size:30px; color:white; font-weight:600 margin-bottom:30px; text-shadow:5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);}
.gran_slider_small_container{width:100%; height:10vh; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));}
.active_slider{display:flex; opacity:1;}
.active_dot{background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);}
/*GRAN SLIDER END*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gran_slider_maincontainer" style="">
    <div class="gran_slider_big_container" style=" ">
     <i class="prev fa fa-chevron-left" style=""></i>
  <i class="next fa fa-chevron-right" style=""></i>
        <div class="gran_slider_big_navegation_container" style=" "></div>
     <div class="gran_slider_big_item_container slider fade" style="">
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_gradient_overlay" style=""></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_image move" style="background-color:red;"></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_container from_right_to_bottom" style=" ">
       <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_title" style="">Titulo</span>
    <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_description" style="">Esta es una descripción que se mueve hacia la derecha, empezando por fuera de la derecha.</span>
   </div>
     </div>
  <div class="gran_slider_big_item_container slider fade" style="">
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_gradient_overlay" style=""></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_image move" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_container from_right_to_bottom" style=" ">
       <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_title" style="">Titulo</span>
    <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_description" style="">Esta es una descripción que se mueve hacia la derecha, empezando por fuera de la derecha.</span>
   </div>
     </div>
  <div class="gran_slider_big_item_container slider fade" style="">
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_gradient_overlay" style=""></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_image move" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_container from_right_to_bottom" style=" ">
       <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_title" style="">Titulo</span>
    <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_description" style="">Esta es una descripción que se mueve hacia la derecha, empezando por fuera de la derecha.</span>
   </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gran_slider_small_container" style=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `index = $(this).eq();` returns an object not an index. So you could remember the index like this: `'<span class="dot" data-index='+index+'></span>'` within your each function and get a certain index like this: `index = $(this).data("index");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function which is called when `dot` is clicked, you are setting the index variable to be the `.eq()` of that dot. You're also printing this to the console, which prints an object rather than the index (which I assume is what you're hoping to get from this function). Because you can't exactly get an index from an entire object, your slider code does run, but can't find any sliders matching an index with an object (since there won't be any).

Therefore, instead of saying

`index = $(this).eq();`

you may want to say this instead:

`index = $(this).index();`

This will set the index variable to be that of the dot that was clicked on, which will then update the slider to that. I'm aware that this doesn't fix the buttons (the active button will remain displayed even when clicking others), but I'm not sure if that's within the scope of your question.